Prove $\operatorname{ord}(x)$ is finite and equal to $\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{ord}(x_1),\operatorname{ord}(x_2))$
Let $G_1, G_2$ be groups and $x_1 \in G_1, x_2 \in G_2$ be elements of finite order.
Let $x=(x_1,x_2) \in G = G_1 \times G_2.$ Prove that the order of $x$ is finite and equal to
$\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{ord}(x_1),\operatorname{ord}(x_2)).$
Here is what I have done:
Let $\operatorname{ord}(x_1)=n$ and $\operatorname{ord}(x_2)=m,$ then we know that
$$ \langle x_1 \rangle   \cong \mathbb{Z}_n $$
$$ \langle x_2 \rangle   \cong \mathbb{Z}_m $$
So we have that
$$ \langle x \rangle   \cong \mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_m $$ and hence we see that the order of $x$ is also finite.
We also see that the $\operatorname{ord}(x) = nm = \operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{ord}(x_1),\operatorname{ord}(x_2)).$
Is this proof correct? Help and solutions are very welcome.

$\mathbb{Z}_N \times \mathbb{Z}_M$ is not always cyclic group. And $nm$ not always equal to LCM of $n$ and $m$.

From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: "A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."

This is likely a duplicate too.

May be think in this way:
Let $n_1 = \operatorname{ord}(x_1)$ and $n_2 = \operatorname{ord}(x_2)$. What is meant (using definition of order) by these?

$n_1$ and $n_2$ are the smallest positive integers such that $x_1^{n_1} = e_1$ and $x_2^{n_2} = e_2$, where $e_1$ and $e_2$ are the identity elements of $G_1$ and $G_2$, respectively.

Then consider the element $x = (x_1, x_2) \in G_1 \times G_2$. Again what is meant by the order of $x$?

The order of $x$, denoted $\operatorname{ord}(x)$, is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $x^k = (e_1, e_2)$.

So what does this tell us?

This means we have $x_1^k = e_1$ and $x_2^k = e_2$.

So here we want to show that $k = \operatorname{lcm}(n_1, n_2)$.
Now by the definitions of $n_1$ and $n_2$, we can say $k$ must be a multiple of both $n_1$ and $n_2$. Therefore, $k \geq \operatorname{lcm}(n_1, n_2)$.
Now let $N = \operatorname{lcm}(n_1, n_2)$. By definition of the least common multiple, $N$ is a common multiple of $n_1$ and $n_2$. Thus, we have
$$
x_1^N = e_1 \quad \text{and} \quad x_2^N = e_2,
$$
which implies
$$
(x_1^N, x_2^N) = (e_1, e_2) \quad \text{or} \quad x^N = (e_1, e_2).
$$
Now aging by the definitions of $k$, we can say $N$ must be a multiple of $k$.
Therefore, $N = \operatorname{lcm}(n_1, n_2)\geq k$.
So we got so far:

$k \geq \operatorname{lcm}(n_1, n_2)$ and $\operatorname{lcm}(n_1, n_2)\geq k$.

Hence $k = \operatorname{lcm}(n_1, n_2)$.
Thus we have shown that the order of $x$ is finite and equal to
$$
\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{ord}(x_1), \operatorname{ord}(x_2)).
$$

A key observation is if $k$ is a multiple of both $m$ and $n$ it can be seen that,
$$x^k=(x_1^k, x_2^k)=(x_1^{(k_1\cdot n)}, x_2^{(k_2 \cdot m)})=(x_1^{n^{k_1}}, x_2^{m^{k_2}})=e$$
where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are positive integers. It implies that, $x^{\text{LCM}(n, m)}=e.$
Let $p<\text{LCM}(n, m)$ and $x^p=e$. It implies that
$$x^p=(x_1^p, x_2^p)=(e_1 ,e_2)$$
By the definition of order, $n$ divides $p$ and $m$ divides $p$, so $\text{LCM}(n, m)\leq p$. A contradiction.
